# Probability interview type question

Tags: probability, contest-math

I am sorry if the title isn't very helpful, but I didn't know how to class the question further...
Anyway here is the question:

> What is the probability that among $25$ people at least one person was born in each month? (So someone was born in January, someone was born in February,... and someone was born in December)

Here is my approach:

I assign $12$ people to each month and then try to calculate the number of ways the remaining $13$ people can be distributed among the $12$ months. Finally I divide this quantity by the total number of possible birth month arrangements, which is $12^{25}$. I assume that order doesn't matter.
To calculate the number of ways $13$ people can be assigned to $12$ months I consider the following cases separately:

1) all $13$ remaining people were born in the same month. Since there are $12$ months, we have $12$ possibilities.

2) all people except one person were born in the same month. This gives $12 \cdot 11$ possibilities.

3) all people except two were born in the same month. This gives $12 \cdot 11^2$ possibilities.

By now I observe the pattern of a geometric series of the form

$$ 12 \cdot ( 1 + 11 + 11^2 + 11^3 + 11^4 +... 11^{12}) $$

which can be written as

$$ 12 \cdot \left( \frac{1- 11^{12}}{1-11}\right) $$

I stop at $ 11 ^{12}$ since at that point 12 of the thirteen remaining people have been assigned to every month in the year and only one person remains. Hence we must multiply the number of possibilities by 12:

$$ 12^2 \cdot \left( \frac{1- 11^{12}}{1-11}\right) $$

Finally I divide by $12^25$ to get:

$$\text{probability}~=  12^2 \cdot \left( \frac{1- 11^{12}}{1-11}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{12^{25}}$$

I am not at all sure whether or not my approach or final solution is correct. If anyone could confirm my insecurities where the question is concerned or affirm my solution I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks for any help!

Comment: I don't see how to make this approach work.  The problem is that it involves overcounting...it's the same if you assign person $A$ to January and then, in the second round, put $N$ in January or if you first assign $N$ and later $A$.   Better, I think, to proceed by Inclusion Exclusion.

Comment: @ lulu I am sorry, I don't quite see how I over counted. Could you explain further? Also I am not really familiar with inclusion/exclusion, so if you could elaborate on that part I would be grateful as well !

Comment: Well, what are you trying to calculate?  If you are just trying to compute the number of $12-$tuples of positive integers that sum to $25$ you could use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) but I don't see the point of that as the $12-$tuples are not equiprobable.  I thought you were trying to count actual assignments which would be equiprobable but then you are overcounting for the reason I said (you count $(AB,\cdots)$ and $(BA,\cdots)$ as two different cases which they are not).

Comment: You may want to read up on the classic coupon collector’s problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll proceed by [The Principle of Inclusion Exclusion or PIE for short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Toward that end, we first specify $k$ months and ask for the probability that our selection misses these $k$.  That is clearly $\left(\frac {12-k}{12}\right)^{25}$.

Now we remark that there are $\binom {12}k$ ways to specify the missing $k$ months.

PIE then tells us that the answer you want is $$\sum_{k=0}^{11} (-1)^k\times \left(\frac {12-k}{12}\right)^{25}\times \binom {12}k\approx .1819$$

Comment: clean! +1 $\, $

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late reply... I like your solution !